# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error. Session setup failed

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, driver

I know these types of questions are already there but provided solution is not working for me.In my application there is no version mismatch b/w driver and PostgreSQL server. I have not found any other solution for this.

I am using PostgreSQL server 9.4 and postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp"></property>
</bean>
```

pg_hba.conf is as follows:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

postgresql.conf is as follows

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432         
max_connections = 100
```

I have also check the netstat o/p .

```
TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the connection string, please.

Comment: OK. That looks pretty standard. Next thing to check is whether the server is actually up on that port on localhost serving via TCP. Can you also add the contents of `pg_hba.conf` (the lines which are not commented out), and from `postgres.conf`, the `listen_addresses` line if it's not commented out, the `port` line, and all settings relating to `ssl`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have provided the details.SSL setting in postgres.conf are commented out.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the Java program on the same host as the PostgreSQL server? Can you successfully open a socket to port 5432 there? Are you passing the username and password through properties or adding them as parameters to the URL?

Comment: Yes both java program and postgres are running on my local machine.                      I am using Spring framework DataManagerDataSource class and passing the properties.See in my question.

Comment: That looks like ipv6. Can you verify for ipv4?

Comment: TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. 
Just change the port number 5432 to 5433 at **postgresql.conf**.
Restart your system.

**postgresql.conf** file location in windows: **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data**

Hope it will help you.