# I'm getting PSQLException when I try to connect to DB

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, database-connection

What could be causing this?

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error.  Session setup failed.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:905)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:834)
    org.apache.jsp.login_005fsave_jsp._jspService(login_005fsave_jsp.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)

root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error.  Session setup failed.
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:381)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:94)
    org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:116)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
    org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:369)
    org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:245)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    org.apache.jsp.login_005fsave_jsp._jspService(login_005fsave_jsp.java:107)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on your configuration file

You may should check this post : [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error. Session setup failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091471/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-protocol-error-session-setup-failed)